# Angular2 CLI Angular-Meteor component creation

Tags: angular, meteor, typescript, angular-cli, angular-meteor

I was playng with Angular2 CLI and Meteor.
I've noticed that when I generate a component with Angular2 CLI, if I want to include it inside another module I have only to include it and insert it inside the declarations array of that module.
[image]

menu.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { MenuItem } from './menu-item';                                         
import { MENUITEMS } from './mocks';

@Component({
  selector: 'menu',                                                                                 
  templateUrl: './menu.component.html',                                         
  styleUrls: ['./menu.component.css']
})

export class MenuComponent implements OnInit {

  menuItems: MenuItem[];                                                                        

  constructor() { }                                                                                 

  ngOnInit() {
    this.menuItems= MENUITEMS;                                                          
  }                                                                                                                 

}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { MenuComponent } from './menu/menu.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { TrendsComponent } from './trends/trends.component';
import { ControllerComponent } from './controller/controller.component';
import { WaterPlantComponent } from './water-plant/water-plant.component';
import { DocsComponent } from './docs/docs.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    MenuComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    TrendsComponent,
    ControllerComponent,
    WaterPlantComponent,
    DocsComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: 'home', redirectTo: '', pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
      { path: 'trends', component: TrendsComponent },
      { path: 'controller', component: ControllerComponent },
      { path: 'waterplant', component: WaterPlantComponent },
      { path: 'docs', component: DocsComponent }
    ])
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

With Meteor, it only works after I add an index.ts into the menu.component folder:

index.ts

```
import { MenuComponent } from './menu.component';

export * from './menu.component';
```

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { PARTIES_DECLARATIONS } from './parties';
import { MenuComponent } from './menu/menu.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ...PARTIES_DECLARATIONS,
    MenuComponent
  ],
  bootstrap: [
    AppComponent
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Could the reason be the "module" of the compiler (inside the tsconfig.json), which is ES6 for CLI and jscommon for Meteor?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Your post is quite confusing, you say "With Meteor, it doesn't work until I don't add the file index.ts into the menu.component folder" - do you really mean to say "It only works after I add an index.ts?"

Comment: yes, that's the point. Post edited, thank you

Answer (score 0):

It appears that with Angular CLI, you are using the Angular2 style guide directory structure and not the [Angular-Meteor directory structure](https://angular-meteor.com/tutorials/socially/angular2/folder-structure), which recommends placing explicitly imported files inside of directories named `imports`. Given Meteor's hybrid module system, could it be the case that the [Meteor default load order](https://guide.meteor.com/structure.html#load-order) for files outside of `imports` directories is causing your problem, which is resolved by the change of load order for `MenuComponent` created by the `export` statement in `index.ts`?